# Sentry raven installation only shows example exception

Tags: node.js, sentry, raven

I installed Sentry with docker: https://hub.docker.com/_/sentry/

I've used the nodejs bindings to send exceptions using the example here: https://docs.sentry.io/on-premise/clients/node/

I've sent many error events but it only seems to show the example exception only.

How do I configure it to log new exception / errors?

I've looked through

```
/etc/sentry/sentry.conf.py
/etc/sentry/config.yml
```

Comment: What kind of Node app? An express app? Or just a short-lived script?

Comment: Well, I tried just running something in the node repl env and included it in an express app. Both times logged the same exception. I can see that it is making to sentry because I see the event count incrementing.